How can I set a combobox WPF visuals in C# only?
I'm trying to setup WPF forms by C# only. But I'm stuck at setting the visuals for a combobox.
I've tried a lot of different approaches and found some near solutions, but I'm not succeeding.
Below a picture of the form I scripted:

I would like to set the visuals of unopened combobox like the items in the dropdownlist. So the unopened combobox also is black and the text is white.
The values for the properties don't need to come out of these items. These are passed to the window by a custom class.
I've read about setting up styles and found the below peace of code somewhere on stackoverflow. I've tried several things and tried to find the info on learn.microsoft.com but can't find it.
Style MyButtonStyle = new Style();

ControlTemplate templateButton = new ControlTemplate(typeof(Button));

FrameworkElementFactory elemFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
elemFactory.SetBinding(Border.BackgroundProperty, new Binding { RelativeSource = RelativeSource.TemplatedParent, Path = new PropertyPath("Background") });

templateButton.VisualTree = elemFactory;

elemFactory.AppendChild(new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter)));

MyButtonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Button.BackgroundProperty, Value = Brushes.Yellow });
MyButtonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Button.TemplateProperty, Value = templateButton });

Trigger styleTrigger = new Trigger { Property = Button.IsMouseOverProperty, Value = true };
styleTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Button.ForegroundProperty, Value = Brushes.Violet });
styleTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Button.BackgroundProperty, Value = Brushes.Red });

MyButtonStyle.Triggers.Add(styleTrigger);

I would like to have, if possible, a sample code to show me how to setup the combobox visuals by C# only. Or if I'm missing a property of the combobox to do this like Name or other simple settings please let me know.

It is unclear what your exact problem is. Do you just want to have white text on black background for the items in the dropdown?

I've addited the question. Thanks for your reply Clemens. "So the unopened combobox also is black and the text is white. "

I hate the combobox. As far as i have learned, if you want precise overrides on the style, you have to reimplement the entire combobox style (a few hundred lines of XAML). that way you can get exactly what you want. The only other way is set the style of a TextBlock or other element local to the combobox.
